# How is stack memory consumption calculated?

Tags: c, stack, embedded

I need to calculate the stack memory consumption of my program.
gcc's `-fstack-usage` only calculates the stack usage of function, but does not include an additional function call in that function as far as I understand.

```
void test1(){
    uint32_t stackmemory[100];
    function1();                    //needs aditional stack, say 200 Bytes
    uint32_t stackmemory2[100];
}

void test2(){
    uint32_t stackmemory[100];
    uint32_t stackmemory2[100];
    function1();                   //needs additional stack, say 200 Bytes
}
```

Which test() function uses less stack? I would say test1(), as the stack is freed after the function1() call. Or does this depend on the optimization level -Os/-O2...?

Does the compiler allocate memory in test1() for all its static variables, as soon as the function is entered? Or is stackmemory2[100] allocated when the line is reached?

Comment: What is stopping you from experimenting?

Comment: @P__J__: The fact that experimental results are not reliable indicators of compiler specifications; potential future software changes; or variations due to changes in command-line switches, source code, or other circumstances.

Comment: @EricPostpischil is my DV clue correct?

Comment: @EricPostpischil if what you say were the only answer the OP might as well give up now, mightn't he? But compilers are basically deterministic-ish otherwise software development using them would be impossible. Experimental results will be useful information but yes must be measured in and recorded against specific setup and environments like those you mention and not taken as simple constants applicable to all possible compilations.

Comment: @barny it is an obvious nitpick. Generally speaking C does not know what the stack is. I expect more similar comments. For example what stack on manufactured in the early 70 soviet stackless computer :)

Comment: @barny: My comment is not an answer to the OP’s question; it is an answer to P__J__’s comment, which proposes an inappropriate means of answering the question. To OP’s question, there is no general answer. Evaluating the stack use of any particular program is highly specific to circumstances. If you really want to evaluate the stack use to, say, ensure a program does not overflow the stack, then a detailed examination of that particular program is necessary, in the environment in which it is to be used.

Comment: @barry: Apple’s LLVM has a feature to report when stack use of routines exceeds a requested amount, but it is of use only in restricted situations, such as ensuring that kernel extensions and drivers do not exceed the limited kernel stack. In general user-level programs, recursion, variable-size stack frames, and massive call trees make stack analysis impractical. So, no, my comment is not a nitpick; it is a warning that stack size analysis is a challenging, complicated task that must be approached with care, not given flippant answers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil he asked `Which test() function uses less stack?`  My answer is - will use exactly the same. When optimizing it will be zero for the automatic variables

Comment: @EricPostpischil the second question: `as soon as the function is entered? Or is stackmemory2[100] allocated when the line is reached` see my answer

Comment: @jonnyx - there are no static variables in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you need to combine call-graph information with the .su files generated by `-fstack-usage` to find the deepest stack usage starting from a specific function.  Starting at `main()` or a thread entry-point will then give you the worst-case usage for that thread.

Helpfully the work to create such a tool has been done for you as discussed [here](https://dzone.com/articles/gnu-static-stack-usage-analysis), using a Perl script from [here](https://dlbeer.co.nz/oss/avstack.html).

ARM's `armcc` compiler (as used in Keil ARM-MDK) has this functionality [built-in](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124223721.htm) and can include detailed stack analysis in the link map, including the worst-case call path and warnings of non-deterministic stack usage (due to recursion for example).

In my experience observing the behaviour of several compilers, the stack-frame is typically defined for the lifetime of the function regardless of the lifetime and scope of the variables declared.  So the two versions in that case will not differ.  Without declaring them `volatile` the optimiser will likely remove both arrays in any event.  However you should not rely on any observations in this respect being universal - it implementation rather then language defined.

Comment: @jonnyx you are of course welcome, but to be clear I just Google'd it - I have never used it  - hope it works for you.

Answer (score -2):

> Which test() function uses less stack? I would say test1(), as the
>   stack is freed after the function1() call. Or does this depend on the
>   optimization level -Os/-O2...?

They allocate exactly the same memory on the stack. And exactly at the same moment :)

```
test1:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 800 <- on stack allocation
        mov     eax, 0
        call    function1
        nop
        leave
        ret
test2:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 800 <- on stack allocation
        mov     eax, 0
        call    function1
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

The only difference is that unused variables when optimizations are on will be completely removed.

> Does the compiler allocate memory in test1() for all its static
>   variables

You don't have any static variables in your example, only the automatic ones

Static variables are not allocated on the stack as they remain their values between the function calls.

godbolt.org/z/j9-VQq

Comment: This assembly code cannot be the result of compiling the code shown in the question as the code shown in the question fails to compile for multiple reasons. With some straightforward additions, I was able to produce a similar result with Apple’s LLVM—but only without optimization. With optimization, the stack usage drops from about eight hundred bytes to about sixteen. So this answer presents an incorrect picture of stack use.

Comment: thanks, didn't you forget the additional 200 Bytes from function 1? These 800 Bytes come from the allocation of two stackmemory[100] variables, as the output of -fstack-usage would tell me. So the total stack consumption of this functions would be 1000 right? In both cases, does it not matter if after the function call the consumed memory is freed again?

Comment: @P__J__: The linked code contains `#include` statements that are not present in the original. Additionally, it is compiled with a non-standard C variant.

Comment: There is no dispute that something had to be included. That does not alter the fact that you presented assembly that **was not generated with the code shown in the question** and for which **the difference was not stated**. You left information out of the answer. Further, I did not say that that omission made the answer invalid (the answer is useless for other reasons) but merely stated it to make it clear that, to properly discuss the code, **complete information must be presented**.

Comment: The chief complaint with the answer is not that it is missing information to reproduce the results it claims but that it presents results that are useless in real software—results for unoptimized code that would not be used in production. It omits discussion of how optimizations would affect stack use in various ways. For example, a function that contained both `int x[300];` and `int y[300];` but used them with entirely disjoint lifetimes should be optimized by the compiler to use only 300 `int` for both arrays.

Comment: Or, for another example, if a routine uses `int x[300];` only inside a conditional statement, a compiler could choose not to allocate it unless the conditional statement were entered. There are numerous variations, regarding which this answer illuminates nothing.

Comment: Do not mess with another scopes - as the question was completely different

Comment: P__J__: In support of your answer, see clause 6.2.4/6 of the standard, which applies because the arrays are not variable-length. This essentially requires space for both arrays to be reserved at the beginning of the block. Of course, one could argue that the as-if rule could allow that requirement to be voided; I can't offhand think of a way of observing the allocation prior to the allocation which doesn't have involve UB but demonstrating that there is no such mechanism strikes me as difficult. (Of course, we know that optimising compilers might completely eliminate unused variables.)